# "Request scope has already been shut down" jersey error in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jersey, wiremock

I'm writing a unit test which mocks out a resource using WireMock. I'm mocking my endpoint to throw an exception, e.g.:

```
    stubFor(
            post(urlEqualTo("/myEndpoint"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(errorCode)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withBody(errorJson)));
```

The relevant part of my client class which is under test here is:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public MyClient() {

    private Client client;
    private String baseUrl;

    ...

    public MyDto createObject(MyDto myDto) throws ClientErrorException {
        String resourcePath = MessageFormat.format("myEndpoint");

        return client.target(baseUrl)
                .path(resourcePath)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(myDto, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), MyDto.class);
    }
}
```

In my unit test I'm trying to use junit's ExpectedException to catch and assert on the returned error, e.g.:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void test_returnsError() {
    ...

    thrown.expect(NotAuthorizedException.class);
    thrown.expect(NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher.hasStatusAndError(401, UNAUTHORISED_ERROR));

    myClient.createObject(new MyDto());
}
```

Where NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher is my own customised matcher class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<NotAuthorizedException> {

    public static NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher hasStatusAndError(int status, ErrorDescription entity) {
        return new NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher(status, entity);
    }

    private final int expectedStatus;
    private final ErrorDescription expectedError;

    private int actualStatus;
    private ErrorDescription actualError;

    private NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher(int expectedStatus, ErrorDescription expectedError) {
        this.expectedStatus = expectedStatus;
        this.expectedError = expectedError;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(NotAuthorizedException exception) {
        actualStatus = exception.getResponse().getStatus();
        actualError = exception.getResponse().readEntity(ErrorDescription.class);
        return expectedStatus == actualStatus && expectedError.equals(actualError);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendValue(actualStatus)
                .appendText(" was found instead of ")
                .appendValue(expectedStatus)
                .appendText(" and ")
                .appendValue(actualError)
                .appendText(" was found instead of ")
                .appendValue(expectedError);
    }

}
```

When my matcher tries to do exception.getResponse().readEntity(ErrorDescription.class), I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request scope has been already shut down.
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.retrieveCurrent(RequestScope.java:239)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:416)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:108)
        at MyProject.NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher.matchesSafely(NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher.java:28)
        at MyProject.NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher.matchesSafely(NotAuthorizedExceptionStatusMatcher.java:8)
        at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
        at org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.matches(AllOf.java:27)
        at org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher.matches(DiagnosingMatcher.java:12)
        at org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher.matchesSafely(StacktracePrintingMatcher.java:29)
        at org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher.matchesSafely(StacktracePrintingMatcher.java:14)
        at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
        at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:12)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
        at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.handleException(ExpectedException.java:252)
        at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$000(ExpectedException.java:106)
        at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:241)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule$1.evaluate(WireMockRule.java:67)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

This same code seems to work if I use a try-catch block to assert on the exception, but I prefer the ExpectedException approach. Any ideas what might be the cause here? I suspect it's a combination of the frameworks I'm using but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: The response body can only be read once. I think the problem is somewhere there. In your matcher you are trying to `readEntity`. Just glanced at the code, but I would imagine that's a good place to start looking.

Comment: I had read about that but I checked and I'm just trying to read it the once. Unless it's also being read somewhere else inside one of the dependencies I'm using. Also I don't think that would explain why it seems to work when I replace the thrown.expect with the try-catch block approach. My gut feeling is it's something implicit to the thrown.expect approach which is causing the issue.

Comment: In your client, that does an implicit read. You maybe be able to get a `Response` in your client, instead of the dto, then call [`Response.bufferEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#bufferEntity--), then you can return `response.readEntity(Dto)`.I think that should do the trick

Comment: Ahhh thanks I think you've given me a very helpful hint in the right direction! The client code I provided I had to simplify quite a lot because we make heavy use of Java generics so I didn't want to overcomplicate the provided code snippet. However I think you're absolutely correct - I'll get back with an update shortly to hopefully confirm the issue is resolved :)

Comment: I think we have a fundamental design problem in that our client API specifies an explicit type of object (MyDto) as the return type. However, in the case where our server throws an error it can return a different type of object (ErrorDescription). After some discussion I think we're going to try migrating to a BiConsumer type of API, which I think is superior as it allows the API to be more explicit to the user about what can be returned, and forces the user to handle the error case. Thanks for your help again, I think we're on a better path now!

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this in the client. 1) Get the response as  a `Response` object. 2). Check the status code 3). If error code, extract response and throw custom exception with extracted error description, else extract dto from response and return. This way the user of the client can handle any exceptions, which will have the error description.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that this is caused by the order of the Rules in your test class.  It's sounds strange, but if the order of the rules are interpreted as *[WireMock, ExpectedException]* then the junit framework actually builds them in that order.   The rules are designed as decorators around your test, such that each rule is allowed to take action before any @Before blocks, and after any @After.

So in the example listed above, where the rules are resolved *[WireMock, ExpectedException]* then the execution order will be:

1. WireMock start server
2. ExpectedException init (if any)
3. @Before execution
4. Perform Test
5. @After execution
6. ExpectedException evaluation and action
7. WireMock shut down server

I think this case is actually the one you're looking for.

If we switch the order of WireMock and ExpectedException though:

1. ExpectedException init (if any)
2. WireMock start server
3. @Before execution
4. Perform Test
5. @After execution
6. WireMock shut down server
7. ExpectedException evaluation and action

Then by the time the ExpectedException rule is allowed to assess the Response in the Exception all services and state have been destroyed by Wiremock.

---

Using the **RuleChain** will guarantee your rule ordering, and fixes the issue (to the extent I was able to emulate it).

> Swap out the **passOrder** and **failOrder** chains to see the test fail!

```
public class WiremockTest {

    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();    
    @Rule
    public RuleChain passOrder = RuleChain.outerRule(wireMockRule).around(thrown);
    //public RuleChain failOrder = RuleChain.outerRule(thrown).around(wireMockRule);

    @Test
    public void exampleTestExpectConnectionException() throws Exception {
        thrown.expect(ConnectionObjectContainer.class);

        //Custom matcher that gets something from the cached connection after the failure occurs.
        thrown.expect(new BaseMatcher<ConnectionObjectContainer> (){

            public boolean matches(Object item) {
                ConnectionObjectContainer container = (ConnectionObjectContainer) item;
                try {
                    //XXX This line is intended to mimic the NotAuthorizedException class behavior
                    System.out.println(container.getResponseCode());

                } catch (IOException exception) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(exception);
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                //Not used in sample
            }});


        stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/my/resource/[0-9]+")).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200).withHeader(
            "Content-Type", "text/xml").withBody("<response>Some content</response>")));

        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8089/my/resource/121");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        throw new ConnectionObjectContainer(con);
    }



    /**
     * My Exception class that caches the HttpURLConnection and provides an accessor for the response code to the Matcher of my 
     * ExpectedException configuration.
     * 
     * @since Jun 17, 2016
     *
     */
    public class ConnectionObjectContainer extends Exception {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        public ConnectionObjectContainer(HttpURLConnection conn) {
            this.connection = conn;
        }

       public int getResponseCode() throws IOException {
            return connection.getResponseCode();
        }
    }


}
```